# gTTS with python not working

Tags: python, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech-to-text

I am working on a speech recognition project using gTTS. The problem is, when i run the code, the system doesn't respond to it. (It won't answer to my query) I tried as per my knowledge but couldn't solve it. I would really appreciate if anyone could help me fix this. Thanks very much in advance. 
Here is my code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from time import ctime
import time
import os
import pyaudio
from gtts import gTTS


def speak(audioString):
    print(audioString)
    tts = gTTS(text=audioString, lang='en')
    tts.save("audio.wav")
    os.system("audio.wav")


def recordaudio():
    # Record Audio
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        print("Say something!")
    audio = r.listen(source)
    time.sleep(2)
    # Speech recognition using Google Speech Recognition
    data = ""
    try:
        data = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print("You said: " + data)
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))

    return data


def ADA(data):
    if "how are you" in data:
        speak("I am fine")

    if "what time is it" in data:
        speak(ctime())

    if "What is your name" in data:
        speak("Call me ADA.")

    if "where is" in data:
        data = data.split(" ")
        location = data[2]
        speak("Hold on Sir, I will show you where " + location + " is.")
        os.system("chromium-browser https://www.google.nl/maps/place/" + location + "/&amp;")


# initialization
time.sleep(2)
speak("Hi Touseef, what can I do for you?")
while 1:
   data = recordaudio()
   ADA(data)
```

I have tested the speechrecognition and gtts libraries separately to check if they are working or not. There is nothing wrong with both of them. But when I try to use them in my actual code, something goes wrong and I can't figure it out.

Here are the code snippets for the libraries.

**gTTS**

```
from gtts import gTTS
import os
tts = gTTS(text='Helllo, Good morning my name is ADA. How can I help you?', lang='en')
tts.save("good.mp3")
os.system("good.mp3")
```

**SpeechRecognition**

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source) 
    print("Say something!")
    audio = r.listen(source)


try:
   print(r.recognize_google(audio))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
   print("Could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
   print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))
```

I'm a student and this is my academic project. Please somebody help me figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from time import ctime
import time
import os
import pyaudio
from gtts import gTTS


def speak(audioString):
    print(audioString)
    tts = gTTS(text=audioString, lang='en')
    tts.save("audio1.wav")
    os.system("audio1.wav")


def recordaudio():
    # obtain audio from the microphone
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print ('Attention! Say something')
        audio = r.listen(source)

    # recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition
    try:
    # for testing purposes, we're just using the default API key
    # to use another API key, use `r.recognize_google(audio, key="GOOGLE_SPEECH_RECOGNITION_API_KEY")`
    # instead of `r.recognize_google(audio)`
        data='something'
        data = r.recognize_google(audio,language='en-US')

    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print ('Attention ! Google could not understand audio')
        data='Could not understand anything'
    except sr.RequestError as e:

       print ('Attention ! Could not request results from Google service.')

    return data


def ADA(data):
    if "how are you" in data:
        speak("I am fine")

    if "what time is it" in data:
        speak(ctime())

    if "What is your name" in data:
        speak("Call me ADA.")

    if "where is" in data:
        data = data.split(" ")
        location = data[2:]
        speak("Hold on Sir, I will show you where " + location + " is.")
        os.system("chromium-browser https://www.google.nl/maps/place/" + location + "/&amp;")


# initialization
time.sleep(2)
#speak("Hi Touseef, what can I do for you?")
while 1:
   data = recordaudio()
   ADA(data)
```

Instead of using gTTS you can use [pyTTsx](http://pyttsx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) which does not require net for operating like

```
import pyttsx
engine = pyttsx.init()
rate = engine.getProperty('rate')
engine.setProperty('rate', rate-40)
engine.say('how are yo8u? 123456789 123 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9')
engine.runAndWait()
```

this.Hope you r problem is solved.

Your new code becomes;

```
import pyttsx


def speak(audioString):
    print(audioString)    
    engine = pyttsx.init()
    rate = engine.getProperty('rate')
    engine.setProperty('rate', rate-40)
    engine.say(audioString)
    engine.runAndWait()
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. Now it is stuck at "Attention, say something" nothing pops up after this. The program continues to pretend it's still listening.

Comment: did you say something in the mic and what os are you using? I tested this on win xp it worked like butter

Comment: here is the video link [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ccI33Aew5fRlNYbE5MeUZ5YU0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I'm using windows 10 x64. I said different words so it might respond but it didn't.

Comment: Let me check the link

Comment: Try using your mic with google chrome to search using voice if it fails to find mic then its a driver problem.

Comment: Works fine with that too. :/

Comment: All right this is working fine on my pc [download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ccI33Aew5fLUZHX3ZCMElLSDQ/view?usp=sharing). If your pc still gives problems try it out on some other pc with windows 7 or 8.1, if it works there then the modules might have issues on windows 10.Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with gtts (didn't generate the audios of Text to speech), I fixed it by updating the module like this:

```
pip install -U gtts
```